# Why are state functions so randomly defined?

Tags: thermodynamics

H = U + PV

G = H - TS

The definition of these state functions seems like a random combination of thermodynamic properties which just turn out to be state functions and independent of the path taken. Is there any convincing reason for why these functions are defined using the equations that they are? Or is this is just experimental analysis showing us that such state functions so defined exist?

Comment: Saying that $H$ "turns out to be" a state function is slightly missing the point. $H$ "turns out to be" a **useful** state function, and this is not obvious until you've worked with it, but you should be able to immediately convince yourself that it is a state function. If you already accept $U$, $V$, and $P$ as state functions, then any combination of them will also be a state function, and thus $H$ is. There's no "experimental analysis" needed beyond that.

Comment: To put it another way: $H$ and $G$ are independent of the path taken because $U$, $P$, $V$, $T$, and $S$ are, and if you know those thermodynamic quantities you can find $H$ and $G$ by definition.

Answer (score 5):

These definitions are Legendre transformations that change the variables in the fundamental thermodynamic relation (each equation can be derived from the first one using the product rule):
$$dU=TdS-PdV$$
$$dH=TdS+VdP$$
$$dF=-SdT-PdV$$
$$dG=-SdT+VdP$$
Hence, we see that these functions have natural variables $U(S,V)$, $H(S,P)$, $F(T,V)$, $G(T,P)$. You can read more about this in any good textbook on thermodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

The design of potentials such as the enthalpy $H$ and Gibbs free energy $G$ is quite deliberate and well-characterized.

The enthalpy is the internal energy we need to create a system plus the work required to push the environment out of the way (useful for adiabatic systems at the surrounding pressure, under which conditions the enthalpy is minimized at equilibrium). The natural relation to work with is now $dH=T\,dS+V\,dP$ for a closed system with no other work. From this we can define all sorts of useful material properties such as the constant-pressure heat capacity $C_P=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$. The study of fluid flow (where we're directing matter streams into areas of different pressure) is greatly aided by this new potential definition.

The Gibbs free energy is the enthalpy minus the free heating of our system that we get from the environment (useful for systems at constant temperature and pressure, under which conditions the Gibbs free energy is minimized at equilibrium). The natural relation to work with is now $dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP(+\sum \mu_i\,dN_i)$, where we include the possibility of matter exchange $dN$ of material $i$ inside and outside the system, with chemical potential $\mu_i$. From this we obtain that the chemical potential of a material—the true arbiter of where matter is driven to move—is the partial molar Gibbs free energy: $\mu_i=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_i}\right)_{V,P,i\neq j}$. The study of chemical reactions (where atoms move from compound to compound) is greatly aided by this new potential definition.

Let's say you're working with a system that can be idealized as maintaining constant surface tension $\sigma$ and constant electric field $E$. We'd expect you to consider defining the "Shridp potential" $\Xi\equiv U-E\Pi-\sigma A$, with electrical polarization $\Pi$ and surface area $A$, to use when considering the near-equilibrium behavior of this system.

**Note the pattern of subtracting any [conjugate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) in which the generalized force is held constant, rather than the generalized displacement. (A constant generalized displacement comes along with the definition of $U$.) The reason is that an existing field does work on your system and increases its energy; this is energy you don't have to provide when conceptually bringing the system into the environment. The pressure–volume term can be confusing as a apparent pattern-breaker until we recall that an increase in pressure *decreases* the volume; pressure is a negative or compressive equitrixial stress.**

The Shridp natural relation would then be $d\Xi= T\,dS-P\,dV-\Pi\,dE-A\,d\sigma$, and you'd use this to define material properties (such as the sudden change in area for a given change in electric field, say) of interest for your particular system.

Practical example: That particular property is $\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial E}\right)_{S,V,\sigma}$. But according to the natural relation, $A$ is just $-\left(\frac{\partial \Xi}{\partial\sigma}\right)_{S,V,E}$. Thus, we could switch the order of differentiation and write $\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial E}\right)_{S,V,\sigma}=-\left(\frac{\partial^2 \Xi}{\partial \sigma\partial E}\right)_{S,V}=-\left(\frac{\partial^2 \Xi}{\partial E\partial\sigma}\right)_{S,V}=\left(\frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial \sigma}\right)_{S,V,E}$; this is called a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations). And perhaps you know $\left(\frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial \sigma}\right)_{S,V,E}$ (the change in polarization for a given change in surface tension) from an unrelated experiment. **This provides a new and useful connection, grounded in the machinery of the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) ($\Xi\equiv U-E\Pi-\sigma A$) and the benefit offered by a carefully defined potential.**

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any convincing reason for why these functions are defined using the equations that they are?

You mentioned two properties, enthalpy and Gibbs energy. To do energy balances we use enthalpy, to figure phase equilibrium we use the Gibbs energy. Is this a convincing enough reason?

We could define "random" combinations of thermodynamic properties, but we don't. For example, $X =  2 (P V)^2- 3.5 (T S)^2$ is both random and a state function. It is also useless, which is why we will not find it in any textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Thermodynamic potentials may look like combinations of state functions without any good reason behind them only if they are introduced as a combination of symbols.

Actually, there is a good theoretical reason. Each thermodynamic potential enables one to get the same thermodynamic information as any other, provided it is given as a function of the proper set of state variables. The theory behind this is the Legendre transform.

A detailed description of Legendre transformation can be found in every good thermodynamics textbook. In brief, the idea is that if we have a function of two independent variables $f(x,y)$, and we find it more convenient to use $z=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as a new independent variable, in place of $x$, we can do by defining a new function (the Legendre transform)
$$
\psi(z,y) = f(x(z,y),y) - z x(z,y).
$$
This is the meaning of $U-TS$. In full detail, it corresponds to inverting the relation
$$
T = T(S,V)=\left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right|_V
$$
to get $S=S(T,V)$. This allows defining the function
$$
F(T,V)=U(S(T,V),V)-T S(T,V).
$$
containing exactly the same information as the original $U(S,V)$, but depending on the variables $T$, and $V$.

Notice that the definition implies
$$
\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right|_V= -S.
$$
Therefore, the Legendre transform of $F$ allows us to recover the original $U$:
$$
U = F + TS.
$$